# BehaivorSubject not keep array and duplicate

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a service and a component, when I add a value this keeps in the array, but when I add other my first  value changes the value to the second

**Service**

```
 export class PrepayService {
  private _carts: BehaviorSubject<ShoppingCart[]>; 
  carts : Observable<ShoppingCart[]>
  dataStore :{
    carts: ShoppingCart[]
  };
  constructor() { 
    this.dataStore = { carts: []};
    this._carts = <BehaviorSubject<ShoppingCart[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.carts = this._carts.asObservable();
  }

  addData(dataObj:ShoppingCart) {
    this.dataStore.carts.push(dataObj);
    this._carts.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).carts);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class TableQuoteComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() quote: QuoteSingle = {};
  cart: ShoppingCart;
  serviceSelected : string;

  constructor(private cartService: PrepayService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmitAdd(){
    this.cart = {};
    this.cart = this.quote;
    this.cartService.addData(this.cart);

  }
}
```

**Second Component**

```
export class PrePayComponent implements OnInit {
  carts: ShoppingCart[];
  constructor(private cartService: PrepayService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.carts.subscribe(carts => this.carts = carts);
    console.log(this.carts);
  }

}
```

**Array Values**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPPUD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcWUH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TableQuote component, you are passing the reference of `cart` property in `cartService.addData` method, and when you add second time you change the `cart` property that changes the first element. You should pass copy of `cart` property like below

```js
this.cartService.addData({...this.cart});
```

or

```js
this.cartService.addData(Object.assign({},this.cart));
```

In javascript or typescript objects and arrays are mutable which means when you pass these variable you actually pass the reference and not just its value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a value by reference.
`Object.assign({}, this.dataStore)` will copy by value instead of reference for the first depth of properties. So carts will not be copied by value, it'll be copied by reference. So I am assuming what is happening here is that you add a new 'Quote' and add to the carts which gets added to the subject stream. But when you re-assign `this.quote` you are also changing the value in the dataStore and thus the subject since it is copied by reference.

To fix this, modify your service's addData() method like so:

```
this.dataStore.carts.push(deepCopy(dataObj); // Here we need to deep copy the ShoppingCart. I don't know what your structure looks like. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataObj)) will work for a cheap and easy deep copy.
this._carts.next(deepCopy(this.dataStore.carts)); // Deep copy the carts object here.
```

I am not very good at explaining things sorry, but basically it's a copy by reference issue you are experiencing. Happens a lot.
Someone else might have a better solution.